# Python code to split cell into multiple rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How can I split cell into multiple rows in pandas dataframe

[image: raw]

[image: result]

Comment: First you must define a rule how (where) the content in a cell is broken into different cells of a column. Seems it needs different rules for different columns.

Comment: I'm reading data from webpage using 
df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]
first image is the output
I want it to convert to multiple row for easier access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not very clear what cells / kind of cells you want to split, but anyway the way to do so is :

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A,B,C', 'D,E', 'F']})

# Use the str.split method to split the values in the 'col1' column
df = df['col1'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename('col1')

# The resulting DataFrame will have multiple rows for each original row
print(df)
```

This code will result something like this output:

```
0    A
0    B
0    C
1    D
1    E
2    F
```

Try to get inspiration from this snippet !